# Parse two columns of pandas as dict

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a dataframe like following

```
firstname,lastname
foo, bar
foo, fooz
bar, foo
foo, bar
```

I want to create a 2d dict from these two columns.
Currently, I am doing

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
first_names = df.firstname.values.tolist()
last_names = df.lastname.values.tolist()
for first, second in zip(first_names, last_names):
    d[first][second] = True
```

I am wondering if there is any inbuilt method that does this "efficiently".

Comment: `zip(df.firstname, df.lastname)` is ok, there is no need to do `.values.tolist()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces this `defaultdict`:

```
defaultdict(dict, {'bar': {'foo': True}, 'foo': {'bar': True, 'fooz': True}})
```

Do you really need the boolean values in the inner dicts?  If not, `groupby()` will get you the same information:

```
grouped = df.groupby('firstname').lastname.unique().to_dict()

grouped
# {'bar': array(['foo'], dtype=object),
#  'foo': array(['bar', 'fooz'], dtype=object)}
```

If you do need the exact dict structure you've created, you can follow up with a dict comprehension:

```
{k:{k2:True for k2 in v} for k, v in grouped.items()}
# {'bar': {'foo': True}, 'foo': {'bar': True, 'fooz': True}}
```